# What happens if you turn on/off our computer multiple times per day

Tags: reboot

I was just wondering if turn on/off a computer several times a day (click start, and clicking shutdown) would cause any issues with the computer, immediately, or in the future? The computer has an SSD if that matters. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you do any research on your own on that matter?

Comment: Is there a reason why you think computers aren't designed for that usage?

Answer (score 4):

If it's high quality product, then you should see nearly no problem at all.

On some extreme cases, some bad-designed parts may suffer excessive voltage/current during power on/off, thus decrease lifespan.

Mechanical HDDs also receive more pressure when powering on, compare to normal working, but your SSD shouldn't bother.